# Accessing JSON data content (problem with names starting with numbers?)

Tags: json

This is sample JSON code received from Wikipedia:

```
{"pages":{"7955":{"pageid":7955,"ns":0,"title":"DNA","links":[{"ns":0,"title":"5' cap"}]}}}
```

Now doing

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data.pages));
```

works fine. However, but

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data.pages.7955));
```

doesn't work. I'm thinking that maybe it's because `7955` starts with a digit, which might be illegal.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data.pages['7955']));
```

or

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data.pages[7955]));
```